# How often do strong master level players (2400+) make illegal moves?

Tags: statistics, grandmaster, illegal-move, international-master

In the [latest podcast from the Chicken Chess Club](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YqlXh1Au6nU&ab_channel=ChickenChessClub), [Laurent Fressinet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_Fressinet) admitted that in his latest tournament, the French rapid and blitz championships, he made an illegal move. He asked the other two podcasters when they last made an illegal move. [Jan Gustafsson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jan_Gustafsson) said that his last illegal move was when he was 17 (so about 1996) and rated about 2400. [Peter Heine Nielsen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Heine_Nielsen) couldn't remember.

So, how often do strong master level players (2400+) make illegal moves?

Comment: If you count moves made in an already dead position as technically illegal, François Labelle did some research awhile back: https://wismuth.com/chess/illegal-moves.html

Comment: It is very hard to answer this statistically, because illegal moves, by nature, are not recorded in databases. For the anecdote, a 2630 GM once made an illegal move against in rapid...

Comment: Related:  [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MPzEFfZe1WQ), [2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zo8EAtSFf38), [3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m5WVJu154F0)